# Laravel Not sending Email

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4

am having some sort of an issue with sending mails from my website with Laravel 4, I followed the on-line documentation but haven't successfully sent a mail with Laravel my code is as show below.

```
Mail::send('emails.contactmail', $data, function($message)
{
    $name = Input::get('name');
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $message->from($email, $name);

    $message->to('info@mysite.org', 'Info at My Site')
            ->subject('Website contact form');
});
```

Comment: Did it work without the `$message -> from(...` part?

And do you've got any errors?

Comment: Have you correctly configured your mail config? What mail driver are you using?

Comment: @that_guy i am using mail and want my app to be able to send mail to every type of email address not just gmail!

Answer (score 0):

I use following code for sending temporary password in case of forgot password

```
public function postForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordRequest $request){

$email=$request->email;
 $objUser=DB::table('users')
                  ->where('email','=',$email)
                  ->select('email','id','first_name','last_name','user_group_id')
                  ->first();

$string = str_random(15);
$pass=\Hash::make($string);

$objUser2=User::find($objUser->id);
$CURRENT_TIMESTAMP=new DateTime();
$objUser2->temporary_pass=$pass;
$objUser2->pass_status=1;
$objUser2->updated_at=$CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
$objUser2->save();            

$data=array("email"=>$email,"pass"=>$string,"first_name"=>$objUser->first_name,"last_name"=>$objUser->last_name);
          $email=array("email"=>$email);
          Mail::send('emails.forgot_password',$data, function($message) use($email) {
          $message->to($email['email'],'MyProject')->subject('Password Recovery ');
          });

          return Redirect::to('auth/login')->with('flash_message','Check your email account for temporary password');
}
```

And I write email template in forgot_password.blade.php which is located in view.emails folder.